# How can I defend and build up early-game in the campaign as Eldar in Dawn of War: Dark Crusade?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

I was just wondering what starting strategies for the Eldar will enable me to set up a base that won't be torn apart during the early game, so that I can actually continue from there.

As in: How do I stop myself from being defeated before I can start?

This question applies to campaign mode where the opponent begins with an established army and map control, rather than the equal footing start of a multiplayer match

Comment: Related: [How to stop the computer from rushing in Dawn of War](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/)

Answer (score 6):

Eldar units are fairly fragile to start with, but make up for it with the upgrades available to them and being quite effective in numbers.

As you are talking about early game tactics against an established enemy, you will want to focus on numbers rather than holding out for vehicles and heavier units.

[**Guardian squads**](http://warhammer-game.narod.ru/wiki/Guardian_Squad.html) with a Warlock in the unit will increase their damage by 20% and also increase your population cap allowing for more units, helping with what should be your main strategy here.

Your next priority should be upgrades for your guardian/warlock squads. The Warlock can be upgraded with Mysticism at a cost of 150 Req and 75 Pow - This will get them a highly effective close combat weapon, a morale boost to the whole squad and a spell that can immobilise enemies for around 7 seconds.

[**Dark Reapers**](http://warhammer-game.narod.ru/wiki/Dark_Reaper_Squad.html) are also good early game, again with upgrades making them even more effective. An Exarch in the squad will increase damage by 15%, and fully upgraded optics will increase damage up to 125%.

If you have a Farseer with the Guide spell, it's apparently bugged and can give a squad over 100% accuracy. This coupled with the Dark Reapers ability to move while shooting should be quite effective.

The Optics and Armour upgrades are essential as early as you can get them.

A good resource for stats and tactics on each Eldar squad can be found [**here.**](http://warhammer-game.narod.ru/wiki/Eldar.html#Guardian_Squad)

And some tips against particular armies can be found [**here.**](http://forums.relicnews.com/showthread.php?91920-1-41-Eldar-Basic-Strategy-Guide)

Comment: Are there particular map regions etc that should be attacked/unlocked first, either for the Personal Guard units or the perks (such as increased req, forward base etc) it gives? Are there any races (or home bases) that pose more of a problem for the Eldar, that should be avoided until having a sizable personal guard and/or most/all of the perks and hero upgrades?

Comment: @Robotnik For map regions - don't venture out too far until you have a few units built up. Advancing too fast will end up in your smaller units being destroyed too quickly leading you to be back where you started. Armies to avoid early on? I'd maybe advise all of them, SM/CSM have decent firepower early on as do Necrons and Tau, Orks could be a problem if they get in close. So I'd suggest the build up to be a fairly all round tactic.

Comment: @LoboDemon I think Robotnik is talking about the campaign.  Which regions on the strategic map are the most valuable (e.g. the one with the space port which allows 2 moves a turn).